# Auto-fill combo box based off of value entered into a text boss

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to develop a database for Coursebooks and available vocabulary presented within said Coursebooks. Upon selection of course books, I want the vocabulary associated with each unit to be presented in a sub-form within a current form.

This is what I want to do:

From a txtbox, enter a value (eg. 10) and have a combo box below auto-populate 10 units so that the user can select which unit they want to attribute each vocabulary word or other pertinent information associated with that particular unit.

Can this be done?

Comment: If you ask if something can be done, the answer is almost always yes, as it is in this case. However, we will not write the code for you to do it. If you are having troubles with a specific issue developing the code for this, you can consult this site. However, provide your attempt and code. Read into "How to ask" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is called cascading (dependent) combobox. Common topic. Search web or this forum.

Comment: Thanks for point me in the right direction @ErikvonAsmuth, I will research this